# Problem while reading document from firestrore in flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am new to `Firebase` I want to read all data of document here is how i am trying to read

This is my function to get data.

```
Future<List<AgencyModel>> getAgencyData() async {
   List<AgencyModel> agencyListModel = [];
    try {
      agencyListModel =  await _db.collection('colelctionName')
        .doc('myDoc')
        .snapshots()
        .map((doc)=> AgencyModel.fromJson(doc.data()!)).toList();
        print('List : ${agencyListModel.length}');
      return agencyListModel;
    } catch (e) {
      debugPrint('Exception : $e');
      rethrow;
    }
  }
```

This is how i am calling the above function

```
getAgencyDetails()  async {
   List<AgencyModel> data = await  fireStoreService.getAgencyData();
    print('Data : ${data.first}');}
```

and this is my models class fromjson function

```
 factory AgencyModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
  return AgencyModel(
    agencyName: json['agencyName'],
    agencyContact: json['agencyContact'],
    agencyAddress: json['agencyAddress'],
    cnic: json['cnic'],
    agencyContactDetails: json['agencyContactDetails'],
    certificatesUrl: json['certificatesUrl'],
    locationUrl: json['locationUrl'],
    earning: json['earning'],
    processing: json['processing'],
    onHold: json['onHold']);}
```

I am not getting any error or exception, Also these two print statements does not work not display anything not even the Strings **List :** and **Data :** i.e

```
print('List : ${agencyListModel.length}');
print('Data : ${data.first}');}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE:
According to the documentation:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#dart_1

It is necessary to distinguish whether you want to retrieve the data only once or listen to changes over the document in real time.

It seems to me like you want to accomplish 1. case that you only want to retrieve data once. In that case.
You should change:

```
agencyListModel = await _db.collection('collectionName')
                           .doc('myDoc')
                           .snapshots()


agencyListModel = await _db.collection('collectionName')
                           .doc('myDoc')
                           .get()
```

Comment: Hello @I.Step i tired the solution you suggest but with .get i get error A value of type 'DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'List<AgencyModel>'.

Comment: @Ahmad Raza I change the link to the currently official documentation.
 Instead of calling .then() after .get() I think you can await get(). 

If you want directly map to custom objects. You should implement converter method fromFirestore() for READ and toFirestore() for WRITE.

Just check the documentation it is in my opinion very well written.
 https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#dart_1